# Microsoft tabletop interaction with android OS

Tags: android, pixelsense, surface

I have a query regarding an application that interacts with Microsoft surface tabletop.
I have to create an app that runs on android OS . The app must provide an icon of all the applications currently running on my surface tabletop.
When the user selects any icon from his android tablet , the application must be opened as a new session on his/her android tablet.
Hence if multiple users select an app on their android tablet ,they must be able to launch the app on their devices on separate sessions?

**Is there any suggestion on how to develop such a solution ? Thanks in advance**
Please see the attached image for the prototype [image]

Comment: Your questions feels to broad, also how does the tabletop interact with the tablets since in all of your description text you use the phrase 'tablet/phone'.

Comment: hi well I am planning to create a C#(tablet) and java(android) app which will communicate like a client server connection and hoping to somehow achieve something similar to remote view but only with active applications in the tablet.